# Prevent "yum remove package" from deleting/renaming config files

Tags: centos, yum, configuration, rpm, delete

I have created a RPM package and it is uploaded to my local yum repository. When I (or future user) install + edit config files of the package and then remove the package (`yum remove <package>`) config files are renamed or removed.

package.spec:

```
%files
%defattr(-, root, root, -)
%dir /etc/something

/etc/something/someA.conf                     # removed
%config /etc/something/someB.conf             # removed
%config(noreplace) /etc/something/someC.conf  # renamed => someC.conf.rpmsave
```

If user remove or update the package, I want to keep modified config files unchanged. How can I do that? Thnaks.

Comment: I now have the same question as you and wish that there was a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

For more details and all combination of `%config*` and `*{rpmsave,rpmnew}` see [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html)

RPM is not a config manager. It recognizes just two states: changed or original file.

It is highly advised to use Ansible for config management. Or you can use `rpmconf` for handling conf updates on the command line.

BTW: A little nitpick: the `%defattr(-, root, root, -)` is not needed since ages. You probably got it from some old tutorial. Just delete it. It is no-operation.